# Is having separate SE accounts a potential security hole?

Tags: discussion, user-accounts

Don't ding me too badly on this one, fella's, because I may be completely wrong.

I've got a StackOverflow account.  My username is PhilMcCrackin and my email is OprahForPresident@gmail.com.  Actually, neither is true, but let's assume they are.

Someone puts this information together and signs up for the Science Fiction SE site using this same info.

Since all SE accounts are linked, has this person just hijacked my account?

Comment: I think they would need the same OpenID for this to work, which they wouldn't have. I don't think the details in your profile are considered at all for this

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Signup/Login requires that one goes through an OpenId provider - that the user authenticate with the OpenId provider.

Sure, someone can put that information in. But they will not get logged in/registered unless they happen to **also** be logged in with the **same** email address on the selected OpenId provider (in this case - Google).

Since someone trying to masquerade as you will not be logged in to your OpenId (they would need your credentials), Stack Exchange will not get authentication/authorization from the OpenId and an account will not be created.

In short - your Stack Exchange account is as safe as your OpenId provider.